# Missing '0' from 24 hour JS clock

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a 24 hour clock function in the top right-hand corner of my site. It loads and displays everything fine, apart from when it reaches "00:00:01", the first zero is missing from the hour counter. E.g. it only shows "0:00:01" until it reaches "10:00:00". Not sure what I am missing.

See image for example:

[image: Example Image]

```js
function startTime() {
  var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var s = today.getSeconds();
  m = checkTime(m);
  s = checkTime(s);
  document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
    h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
  var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}

function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i
  }; // add zero in front of numbers < 10
  return i;
}
```

```html
<body onload="startTime()">
  <div id="txt"></div>
```

Comment: You don't use `checkTime` on `h`.

Comment: And when you do you may need `""+ h + ":" + m + ":" + s;`

Comment: `<script>` tags are not meant to block DOM parsing. place you script tags right before the closing `</body>` tag. That will also help resolving other problems, and make `onload="startTime()"` not needed any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pad the `h` too

Here is a simpler version using better practices

```js
const pad = num => String("0"+num).slice(-2);
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  const container = document.getElementById('txt');
  const tId = setInterval(function() {
    const today = new Date();
    const h = pad(today.getHours());
    const m = pad(today.getMinutes());
    const s = pad(today.getSeconds());
    container.textContent = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
  }, 500)
})
```

```html
<div id="txt"></div>
```

Comment: or check the length of the number `function checkTime(i) { var strNumber = i.toString(); if (strNumber.length = 1) return ('0' + strNumber); return strNumber; }`

Comment: @bron You have mistakes. It is === 1 and not = 1 (assignment) - if you must, then `const pad = n => String(n).length === 1 ?  '0'+n : n;`

Comment: Oops, you're right, ofcourse it is `if (strNumber.length === 1) return ('0' + strNumber);`